# Automatic processing of cube after every 1 hour?

Tags: ssas

I am using Microsoft SQL 2008. In Microsoft Visual Studio, I have created a cube. I want to schedule the processing of this cube after every 1 hour. Can somebody tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it. what's that??

Comment: Create an SSIS package. Add AS processing task. Schedule it with SQL Agent. Done.

Answer (score 5):

On the same solution with your SSAS project create an new SSIS project

- Under SSIS Packages, open the dtsx file
- Go to  Control Flow and select the Analysis Services Processing Task from the SSIS toolbox
- Add the Task to the control flow
- On the connection manager add a new Analysis Services connection and point it to your database cube.
- Edit the SSAS processing task and go to Proccessing Settings
- Add the objects you want to proccess

I usually put two Analysis Services Prossecing Tasks - one for all the dimensions and another for the entire cube -

Now connect to the Intergration services on MSsQL management studio and add your project to the packages.

Follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471507.aspx) to see how you can schedule via the MsSQL agent the SSIS Package.

And you are done!